# How to call Type's nullSafeSet (where to get type instances)

Tags: java, hibernate

I am implementing a UserType in 4.1.0.Final and require calling BlobType.nullSafeSet and Get methods. Before, on called Hibernate.BLOB to access these methods, where does one get an instance of the Types now?

Comment: It's obscure. Can you explain it more clearly or show some code?

Comment: It's a standard method/implementation/question if one has implemented a UserType. Anyway I posted the answer. Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the INSTANCE static property of BlobType contains an instance of BlobType.